# What is the weak formulation of this PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have the PDE:

$u_t = \Delta u + \sin t$

With homogeneous boundary conditions which if I understand correctly means that $u(\partial\Omega) = 0$

I am trying to solve this numerically with FreeFEM++ which only accepts the weak formulation of the problem. So I need to translate my problem into the weak form.

If I understand properly what I must do is multiply my equation on both sides by a test function, and integrate, i.e.

$$\int_\Omega u_t \phi = \int_\Omega(\Delta u + \sin t)\phi$$

Is this correct? Am I missing any differentials?

Comment: Probably you mean $u(\partial\Omega)=0$? To get the weak formulation you're going to want to formally integrate by parts to move the derivatives onto $\phi$.

Comment: Yes! that was a typo, thank you for catching that. Does this mean I integrate both parts or only the LFHS?

Comment: It's common to introduce a test function on a spacetime domain say $[0,T]\times\Omega$ and integrate over all $n+1$ variables so you can move over the $\partial_t$ and the $\Delta$. The left would be $-\int\int u\phi_t$ and the right $\int\int(u\Delta\phi+\sin t\phi)$.